# Setting node attributes in networkx doesn't accept a dict, returns unhashable type

Tags: python, networkx

I'm following network_x documentation here:
https://pelegm-networkx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_node_attributes.html

Which says:

```
>>> G = nx.path_graph(3)
>>> bb = nx.betweenness_centrality(G)  # this is a dictionary
>>> nx.set_node_attributes(G, 'betweenness', bb)
```

I'm trying the same with degree_centrality, I get:

```
>>> degree_centrality_dict = nx.degree_centrality(G)
>>> nx.set_node_attributes(G, 'degree_centrality', degree_centrality_dict)

    683         except AttributeError:  # `values` is a constant
    684             for n in G:
--> 685                 G.nodes[n][name] = values
    686     else:  # `values` must be dict of dict
    687         for n, d in values.items():

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Same for:

```
>>> eigenvector_dict = nx.eigenvector_centrality(G)
>>> nx.set_node_attributes(G, 'eigenvector', eigenvector_dict)
```

Why is this, and how can I correctly set node attributes in networkx?

Answer (score 1):

In [this](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_node_attributes.html) networkx doc, the order of the arguments `values` and `name` is different, which means that they swap `"betweenness"` and `bb`. I tried that and it works:

```py
import networkx as nx

G = nx.path_graph(3)
bb = nx.betweenness_centrality(G)
nx.set_node_attributes(G, bb, "betweenness")  # this is a dictionary
print(G.nodes[1]["betweenness"])
```

This code prints `1.0`.

It also works for the other examples you gave.